# I have a java application running on an IIS server, Will windows performca monitor (Perfmon) will be sufficient for performance analysis

Tags: performance, performance-testing, performancecounter

I have a java application running on an IIS server, Will windows performca monitor (Perfmon) will be sufficient for performance analysis? Or will it just capture server details and not application level details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using perfmon will give you a report about how much memory IIS and java jvm are using, and cpu load, but cant tell you how much of these is used by each application installed in your server

Comment: Thanks Thiago. Would Jconsole give any information regarding the application?

Comment: "JConsole uses the extensive instrumentation of the Java Virtual Machine (Java VM) to provide information about the performance and resource consumption of applications running on the Java platform" you can find some useful help here: [link]https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html[/link]